# Query help for someone who has been using Linq-to-Sql too much lately

Tags: sql

```
Patient 
-------
PatientID

Visit
-----
VisitID
PatientID
HeartRate
VisitDate
```

How do I select all of the patients who have a visit, the date of their **first** visit, and their heart rate at that **first** visit?

Comment: I guess there is a one to many relationship between Patient and Visit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT
  p.PatientID,
  v.VisitID,
  v.HeartRate,
  v.VisitDate
FROM
  Patient p
  INNER JOIN Visit v ON p.PatientID = v.PatientID
WHERE
  v.VisitDate = (
    SELECT MIN(VisitDate) 
    FROM Visit 
    WHERE PatientId = p.PatientId
  )
```

---

EDIT: Alternative version. Same thing. (less obvious, therefore less desirable IMHO)

```
SELECT
  p.PatientID,
  v.VisitID,
  v.HeartRate,
  v.VisitDate
FROM
  Patient p
  INNER JOIN Visit v ON p.PatientID = v.PatientID
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PatientID, MIN(VisitDate) VisitDate 
    FROM Visit 
    GROUP BY PatientID
  ) f ON f.PatientID = p.PatientID AND f.VisitDate = v.VisitDate
```

Comment: hrmm this is close to what i had, i was hoping there was a better way though. thanks so much

Comment: I don't think there is a "better" way to do it. However you define that. If you mean "without using a sub-query"... You could add an INNER JOIN against "(SELECT PatientID, MIN(VisitDate) FROM Visit GROUP BY PatientID)". But that's just the sub-query in disguise.

Comment: more so that youre joining on the patientID / visit date combo. but i think its the only way

Comment: Yes, you could move the WHERE condition of my version 1 query to the join condition (simply replace "WHERE" by "AND"). If it makes you happy. :-) SQL Server will produce the same query plan.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?
Of course the join isn't really necessary here since there are no extra fields in Patient. But I guess IRL there are.

```
select PatientId, HeartRate, VisitDate from Patient p
left join Visit v on p.PatientID = v.PatientId
```

Comment: sorry ened the first visit. and this would be an inner join ;p

Comment: The query is the same, but add a 'SORT BY VisitDate DESC GROUP BY PatientId' to it.

Answer (score 1):

The final query

```
declare @practiceID int 
select 
    isnull(sum(isResponder),0) as [Responders],
    isnull(count(*) - sum(isResponder),0) as [NonResponders]
from (  
    select 
        v.patientID
        ,firstVisit.hbLevel as startHb
        ,maxHbVisit.hblevel as maxHb
        , case when (maxHbVisit.hblevel - firstVisit.hbLevel >= 1) then 1 else 0 end as isResponder
    from patient p 
        inner join visit v on v.patientid = v.patientid 
        inner join practice on practice.practiceid = p.practiceid
        inner join (
            SELECT
              p.PatientID
              ,v.VisitID
              ,v.hblevel 
              ,v.VisitDate 
            FROM Patient p
              INNER JOIN Visit v ON p.PatientID = v.PatientID
            WHERE
                v.VisitDate = (
                    SELECT MIN(VisitDate) 
                    FROM Visit 
                    WHERE PatientId = p.PatientId
                 )
        ) firstVisit on firstVisit.patientID = v.patientID
        inner join (
            select 
                p.patientID
                ,max(v.hbLevel) as hblevel
            from Patient p
                 INNER JOIN Visit v ON p.PatientID = v.PatientID
            group by
                p.patientID
        ) MaxHbVisit on maxHbVisit.patientid = v.patientId
    where
        p.practiceID = isnull(@practiceID, p.practiceID)
    group by
        v.patientID
        ,firstVisit.hbLevel
        ,maxHbVisit.hblevel
    having
        datediff(
            d,
            dateadd(
                day
                ,-DatePart(
                    dw
                    ,min(v.visitDate)
                ) + 1
                ,min(v.visitDate)
            )
            , max(v.visitDate)
        ) >= (7 * 8)
) responders
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP(1) PatientID, VisitDate, HeartRate FROM Visit ORDER BY VisitDate ASC
```

Patient has only PatientID? Not a name or something like that?

Comment: I only posted the relevant columns from patient. Anyway I need the first visit :<

Comment: Then it would be something like this.

Comment: Doesn't he want all the patients with visits?